# Implementing search history for Places autocomplete without manipulating autocomplete fragment UI

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, autocomplete

I am using the Places autocomplete API and followed the documentation to successfully implement autocomplete in my app code. It is working perfectly fine.

However, I am trying to add a search history feature for the autocomplete. The autocomplete uses an AutocompleteFragment which I believe prevents directly manipulating its UI.

I have tried a few different approaches to implement the search history but have been unsuccessful.

Is it possible to programmatically manipulate the UI of the AutocompleteFragment to show a search history? Or is there another way I can implement the search history without directly modifying the fragment UI?

I am implementing this in Java.

I will provide the code that I am using for the autocomplete implementation as a reference.

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated! I've searched around but haven't found a good solution yet for adding search history with the AutocompleteFragment.

XML

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Autocomplete Fragment

```
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
}
           

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
```